# how to include both wincodec.h and d3dx10.h (or d3dx11) files in my project

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, direct3d, wic

i try to include wincodec.h in my project but it gives me errors if i try compile it, i dont have any other header or cpp file in my project.

my code (EDITED to make it more simple to understand the issue):

```
#pragma comment (lib, "windowscodecs.lib")

//it doesn't matter if include here also the Windows.h

//[about the 1st EDIT] i don't include any d3dx (10 or 11) headers here! However the compiler still gives me errors!!!

#include <wincodec.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    return 0;
}
```

and here are the errors i get;

```
Error   C3646   'PixelFormat': unknown override specifier

Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'DXGI_JPEG_AC_HUFFMAN_TABLE' (same error also for DXGI_JPEG_DC_HUFFMAN_TABLE and DXGI_JPEG_QUANTIZATION_TABLE)
```

**All these errors coming from wincodec.h file.**
Also i tried to include the library windowscodecs.lib from Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies but still had the same errors so i removed from there and now i include it here in source.
Anyone knows why i get these errors and how can i fix it?

I use visual studio 2019 (v142), windows sdk 10, iso c++ 17.
Builting as Release, x64.
SubSystem: Windows(/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)

**1st EDIT**:
I just found the problem!
In Library Directories i had this path: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include**, if i remove it, it built fine.

Now the problem is without have this path there, i can't use 2 headers that i need for D3D part: d3dx10.h and d3dx11.h.

Any idea how to solve this problem now?

**2nd EDIT**:
So, i now changed Library Directories to this: `$(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)/include`
and only this error disappeared: *Error   C3646   'PixelFormat': unknown override specifier*

Comment: Try to include #include <windows.h>, not #include <windowsx.h>

Comment: @SimonMourier i tried and had the same errors.

Comment: @yournamehere The posted code builds fine with or without `#include <windows.h>` using `/std:c++17` and the rest of settings left at defaults. What is your project *type*, and did you override `WINVER`, `_WIN32_WINNT` etc to target a particular (older) version of Windows?

Comment: @dxiv where can i see the project type and if i overrided the WINVER, _WIN32_WINNT?

Comment: maybe visual studio bugged or something... indeed i can built it fine in a new project. Very strange issue

Comment: @yournamehere Those macros would normally be under Properties / C/C++ / Preprocessor Definitions, though they could also be explicitly `#define`'d in the sources. One other thing to check, if you compile with `/permissive-` for strict compliance, try removing that from C/C++ / Language / Conformance Mode. Some combinations of VS and SDK versions are known to fail compiling with `/permissive-`.

Comment: @dxiv i found the issue already and i edited my question (in case you didnt saw it), however my issue did not solved yet...
Preprocessor Definitions: NDEBUG;_WINDOWS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions).
I don't have any #define in my code.
Conformance Mode: Yes (/permissive-)

Comment: @yournamehere It's not solved as long as you still get errors ;-) Try removing `/permissive-`. Also remove `/Za` C/C++ / Language / Disable Language Extensions if set.

Comment: @dxiv yes i know it not solved, that's exactly what i said :D... So i just changed it to 'No', but nothing happened. Also changed Language Extensions and this one gave me more errors

Comment: @yournamehere Compiles fine for me (vs 16.7.5, sdk 10.0.19041.0) with `cl /c /std:c++17 /permissive-` but fails if adding `/Za`, both with/without the `d3d` headers. Sorry, don't know what is different in your case.

Comment: @dxiv after a lot reseach i notice that i can include d3dx9.h without problem. This issue appearing when you include d3dx10 or/and 11... Maybe you included the d3d11.h (or 10) and not the d3dx11.h (or 10)? In case to use a d3dx10/11 headers will need to download Microsoft DirectX SDK and include its path at: VC++ Directories/Include Directories. If you really included d3dx10.h (or 11) header & wincodec.h and builted without problem, then idk what to say :/

Comment: @yournamehere I only tried `wincodec.h`, `d3d10_1.h` and `d3d11.h`.  D3DX has been [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d10/d3d10-graphics-reference-d3dx10) since Win8 and I don't have one handy.

Comment: @dxiv i know, but i need this from d3dx11 header: D3DX11CompileFromMemory() (and D3DXCOLOR, but the 2nd it's just a simple struct so i can code it too)

Answer (score 2):

The basic issue you are encountering is that the legacy DirectX SDK contains some headers that 'overlap' with the Windows SDK. For Visual Studio 2010 / Windows SDK for Windows 7 and before, those headers in the DirectX SDK were *newer*, but that's not been true since the Windows SDK for Windows 8. VS 2019 `v142` is using the Windows 10 SDK (17763) or later.

The Windows 8 SDK and Windows 10 SDK already include the bulk of the "DirectX" content including the latest DXGI, Direct3D 9, Direct3D 10, Direct3D 11, Direct3D 12, and D3DCompiler headers/libs.

The Windows 8 SDK and Windows 10 SDK does *not* contain the D3DX9, D3DX10, or D3DX11 utility headers/libraries. Those components are deprecated.

To workaround this issue, you need to:

(a) make sure the DXSDK include/libs paths are *after* the other paths in your VC++ Directories.

(b) explicitly include the Direct3D and DXGI headers before the legacy 'd3dx10.h' or 'd3dx11.h' headers are included. If you rely on the 'd3dx10.h` or 'd3dx11.h' header, then it will always be pulling in the *old* version:

```
#include <dxgi.h>
#include <d3d10.h>
#include <d3d11.h>

#include <d3dx10.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
```

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-) and [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/)

> Ideally you'd remove all use of the deprecated DirectX SDK and not use D3DX10 or D3DX11 at all. You can find a bunch of open source replacements listed [here](https://walbourn.github.io/living-without-d3dx/).

> Note that if you use the `v141_xp` toolset for Windows XP support, that actually uses a Windows 7.1A SDK which is *before* DirectX was integrated and in that case, the legacy DirectX SDK headers are 'newer'.

**UPDATE**: Another option to using the D3DX library without having these header conflicts is to use the [Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX) NuGet package *instead* of the legacy DirectX SDK. Ideally you'd move to those open source replacements instead as D3DX9/10/11 is still quite old.